# Why aren't the matplotlib checkboxes working in pyQt5?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, checkbox, pyqt5

I have a little issue in my code since I have a matplotlib graph with checkboxes (to choose what to plot) but when I open it with Pyqt5 (a Pushbutton) it does open but the checkboxes do not work, we can not touch them. My function works well, but not with Pyqt5, I hope I'm enough precise and I'm sorry if I am not. Here is my code if that can help you :

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QMainWindow, QApplication
import sys
from matplotlib.widgets import CheckButtons
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def graph_check () :
    x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    y1 = [1,1,1,1,3,1]
    y2 = [0,2,1,2,2,1]
    y3 = [4,3,2,0,0,5]
    fig,ax = plt.subplots()
    p1, = ax.plot(x,y1,color = 'red', label = 'red')
    p2, = ax.plot(x,y2,color = 'green', label = 'green')
    p3, = ax.plot(x,y3,color = 'blue', label = 'blue')
    lines = [p1,p2,p3]
    plt.subplots_adjust(left = 0.25, bottom=0.1, right=0.95,top = 0.95)
    # checkbuttons widgets
    labels = ['red', 'green', 'blue']
    activated = [True, True,True]
    axCheckbutton = plt.axes([0.03,0.4,0.15,0.15])
    chxbox = CheckButtons(axCheckbutton, labels,activated)
    def set_visible (label) :
        index = labels.index(label)
        lines[index].set_visible(not lines[index].get_visible())
        plt.draw()
    chxbox.on_clicked(set_visible)
    plt.show()
    # that function does work well, in the end we have a graph with 3 lines and we can make   
    # them visible or not thanks to the checkbox.

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 600, 400)
        self.btn1 = QPushButton('Graph check', self)
        self.btn1.setGeometry(130, 215, 125, 55)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.btn1_onClicked)
        self.show()

    def btn1_onClicked(self):
        graph_check()
        # it works, we can see the graph but it is impossible to use the checkbox...


App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem, as I'm able to toggle all three checkboxes with the graph properly toggling the lines. Please add more details about your configuration: PyQt version (`from PyQt5 import QtCore; print(QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR)`), matplotlib version (`import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.__version__)`), and OS.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. Then, I have done what you asked and I have these results : for the QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR I have "5.15.2" and for matplotlib version, it returns : "3.5.1". Merry Christmas

Comment: @musicamante I do reproduce the problem, are you using a specific environment?

Comment: @eyllanesc I can't reproduce it (meaning that it works as expected) on Linux, with Qt 5.15.2 and matplotlib 3.3.4, just copying the code above to a script and running from the terminal. From what I know, `plot.show()` starts a new event loop if one exists and is not running *or* creates a further one and `exec`s it, then blocking until the plot widget is closed, so the reference to the checkboxes is not garbage collected. Maybe the behavior has changed in later versions of matplotlib?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is caused because "chxbox" is a local variable whose reference will be removed when the function finishes executing. A possible solution is to make it an attribute of another object that has a greater scope:

```py
# ...
plt.chxbox = CheckButtons(axCheckbutton, labels, activated)

def set_visible(label):
    index = labels.index(label)
    lines[index].set_visible(not lines[index].get_visible())
    plt.draw()

plt.chxbox.on_clicked(set_visible)
# ...
```